# ONVIF: 'GetSnapshotUri' save to FTP directly from IP Camera

Tags: c++, linux, gsoap, onvif

I'm able to use 'GetSnapshotUri' from a linux client to get a snapshot from a ONVIF complaint IP camera (dahua) successfully via gsoap c++.

Now, I need to upload this image to a FTP server. The way this would normally be done is to download the jpeg snapshot to the client, rename it and upload it to the FTP server.

I was wondering if there's a way to direct the camera to save the image directly to the FTP server on a 'GetSnapshotUri' action?

Comment: Not easily. FTP and HTTP are not the same protocol, so you need to either get your FTP server to make the `GetSnapShotUri` call, and receive the result, or make your camera send out FTP-protocol. It's a bit like me going to Spain expecting to get everything written in English...

Comment: :D I wanted to have the client function as a standalone device, so I wouldn't prefer having the FTP server making ONVIF calls. Regarding "make your camera send out FTP-protocol", could you please elaborate on how that can be done? I wasn't able to find a way to set the protocol to FTP for 'GetSnapshotUri' or 'CreateProfile', or maybe I didn't get you right.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea if that is possible - depends on the camera. My point is that FTP and HTTP are not the same thing, so you can't simply expect one to receive the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the ONVIF standard supporting this behavior.

It is possible you could script something on some cameras, or do something with the events wsdl on others, but by in large you will have to act as a martial and manage the exchange.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Chris. I decided to download the snapshot locally and upload it to the FTP server via libCURL.